# Delete anchor point in Sketch 3

Tags: sketch-app, anchor-point

I have a shape consisting of three anchor points. Now I want to **delete** one anchor point leaving the space between the two adjacent anchor points empty. So I follow the tried old Illustrator approach, but what happens instead is that when I press Backspace to delete the anchor point the point is removed but the shape border continues now instead between two of the three remaining anchor points (the same thing that would happen if you click an anchor point holding Alt in Illustrator).

I realize this may be a tad hard to follow, so here's what happens in images:

[image]

[image]

And here is a manipulated image of what I would like should happen:

[image]

Do we have any Sketch 3 guru here who know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same issue. Try the Scissors tool!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The scissors tool is also accessible from the menu bar: **Layer › Paths › Scissors**

Answer (score 1):

just stumbled upon you post looking for your answer. Through trial and error I finally found a solution. Once you're in anchor editing mode theres a button in the right panel that reads "open path". Klicking that does the trick. Although it seems quite random wich path disappears, you should be able to make it work with that.

Best,
Pascal

Answer (score 1):

*Thought I'd catch up on Sketch questions ...*

### Sketch sucks at this*

This is a tricky issue in Sketch. It doesn't respond the way us Illy users hope it will. In fact, it's not very smart about it at all.

As @paexthetiker noted, you can just convert to an "open path". The problem is that Sketch simply opens it at the start of the bezier path. Probably not what you're looking for.

### But there is a way

Convoluted though it may be. Let's say I want to knock out the straight line on the left of this folder icon.

[image: In the beginning]

#### Sketch in control

I tried deleting points like an Illy junkie would. Suck.
I tried clicking <kbd>Open Path</kbd>, but Sketch just disconnects the path's start and end point (as it was originally drawn).
I tried first selecting the points to open. Nope.

[image: Mathematically correct]

#### You in control

My workaround is Sketch's boolean functions, or the "Pathfinder" for us old Illustrator guys.

Draw a shape over the area you want to open up, like so.

[image: Two things to make the one you want]

Select both shapes and click the <kbd>Subtract</kbd> boolean / pathfinder option, then the <kbd>Flatten</kbd> option.

[image]

**Congratulations!** You just reset the start and end points of your path! If you dropped that extra shape in the right spot, you'll now get *almost* what you're after when you choose <kbd>Open Path</kbd>.

[image]

After opening the path, you can delete the extraneous points to *finally* complete what should be a simple action.

[image]

> * The good news is, Bohemian Coding (the guys behind Sketch) are
> aggressively attacking little things like this.

Comment: apparently Bohemian Coding still doesn't have their stuff together because we're still running into this issue.

Comment: I haven't tried this feature in a long while, but I heard a rumor that the next version might have some path fixes. Might be worth playing with [the beta](https://www.sketchapp.com/beta/), if you need the features.